# Weekly subscription payment in inapp purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I want to implement inApp purchase where amount is automatically deducted every week.
User don't have to enter the credential again and again.
It just notify user and deduct the amount.

Like news letter feature in the application.
Every week perticular amount is been deducted.
It will ask for inapp credential one time and then it will deduct automatically.

I heard about consumable and non-consumable.
This will be like consumable.
But credential will be asked for every time.

How can i avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the official documents : https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/In-App-Purchase-Guidelines.pdf

Basically, there is 5 type of InApp products which are :

- Consumables
- Non-Consumables
- Auto-Renewable Subscriptions
- Free Subscriptions
- Non-Renewing Subscriptions

And I think you want to use Auto-Renewable Subscriptions, be sure to be compliant with Apple guidelines about what you want to sell.